# How to integrate Google users(oauth2) into Nodejs express API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am new to node.js/express/mongo and I have a noob question to ask. I have set up my own register/login with emails and password on my app with bearer jwt token and the users has to provide email and password to log in. Thanks to this, the password field is required in my user model.
But how do I integrate/add the google users from oauth2 into my database? Do I have to create another model and collection for google users? I can create random password for them and add them to database with other information google provides but is there better solution?
and thank you for taking your time to answer to my stupid question!